# Help on TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm very sorry about dull question, but I am totally confused by TikZ. Would anyone help me to draw following diagram, please?

[image]

What I've done so far is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    every node/.style={{font=\tt},>=stealth'},%
    list/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,%
    draw,>=stealth', rectangle split horizontal}%
    ]
\node at (-1,1) (upperLeftHidden) {};
\node[list] (center) [below right=of upperLeftHidden] {x} %at (0,0)
    edge[<-,bend right=20,shorten <=5pt,>=stealth']
        (upperLeftHidden);
\node [below left=of center] {t}
    edge[<-,bend left=20,shorten <=3pt,>=stealth'] (center);
\node[list] (bot) [below right=of center] {\nodepart{second} f} %at (0,0)
    edge[<-,bend right=20,shorten <=5pt,>=stealth']
        (center)
    edge[->,bend right=20,shorten <=5pt,>=stealth']
        (center.north);
%\node [below left=of bot] {e} % doesn't work for some reason
    %edge[<-,bend left=20,shorten <=3pt,>=stealth'] (bot)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: please show what you have tried so far. That way you learn by mistake rather than just getting a solution.

Comment: A start: TikZ manual, 16.3 Multi-Part Nodes, 48.6 Shapes with Multiple Text Parts (shape: `rectangle split`), 16.11 Connecting Nodes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another variation, unfortunately **morbusg** was faster than me :)

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.multipart,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    every node/.style={{font=\tt},-latex},%
    list/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3, draw, rectangle split horizontal},%
    ]
\node[list, name=adin] at (0,0) {x};
\node[list, name=dwa] at (1,-1) {\nodepart{second} f};
\draw[bend left=10,-latex] (-1,1) to ($(adin.two north) + (-0.1,0.1)$);
\draw[bend right=20,-latex] (adin.two) to ++(-1,-1) node[below] {t};
\draw[bend right=20,-latex] (dwa.one) to ++(-1,-1) node[below] {e};
\draw[bend left=30,-latex] (adin.three) to ($(dwa.two north) + (0,0.1)$);
\draw[-latex,rounded corners,out=-45,in=45] (dwa.three) .. controls (3,-3) and (1.5,3) ..  ($(adin.two north) + (0.1,0.1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** With some improvements thanks to **morbusg**:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.multipart,calc,scopes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    every node/.style={{font=\tt},-latex},%
  list/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3, draw, rectangle split horizontal}]

\node[list, name=adin] at (0,0) {x};
\node[list, name=dwa] at (1,-1) {\nodepart{second} f};

{[-latex]
    \draw[bend left=10] (-1,1) to ($(adin.two north) + (-0.1,0.1)$);
    \draw[bend right=20] (adin.two) to ++(-1,-1) node[below] {t};
    \draw[bend right=20] (dwa.one) to ++(-1,-1) node[below] {e};
    \draw[bend left=30] (adin.three) to ($(dwa.two north) + (0,0.1)$);
    \draw[out=-45,in=45,looseness=4] (dwa.three) to ($(adin.two north) + (0.1,0.1)$);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Haha, that was non-intentional, but looking at your profile's location "Rostov-na-Donu, Russia", this is a nice coincidence. Da Nesaschto!

Answer (score 10):

Here's some ideas:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning,scopes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [ >=latex,shorten >=1pt,
    triplet/.style={
      draw,
      rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
      rectangle split ignore empty parts=false,
      rectangle split horizontal=true, font=\tt}]

  \node [triplet] (x) {x};
  \node [triplet,below right of=x] (f) {\nodepart{two}f};

  {[->]
    \draw (x.two) to[bend right=30] +(-1,-1) node[below] {\tt t};
    \draw (x.three) to[bend left=30] (f.two north);
    \draw ([yshift=1ex]f.three)
      to[out=45,in=75,looseness=2] ([xshift=1pt]x.two north);
    \draw (f.one) to[bend right=30] +(-1,-1) node[below] {\tt e};
  }
  \draw[<-] (x.two north) to[bend right=15] +(-1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, neither did I know about the possibility of `{[->] <draw commands> }`, nor about the `looseness` option. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I agree with zeroth's comment but if you are totally confused by TikZ perhaps  it will be a good idea to help you.

In your diagram, you have : texts and arrows. TikZ gives you a tool named `node` to place text inside a shape. With a node, TikZ defines for you some objects (anchors) to draw correct edges between the nodes.

First we place the nodes:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (e) at (3,1){e}; % {e} label of the node (e) reference or name of the node
\node (t) at (2,2){t};
\node (u) at (0,6){}; 

\node (g) at (4,2){}; 
\node (g) at (5,2){f};   
\node (h) at (6,2){};

\node (x) at (2,4){x}; 
\node (y) at (3,4){};   
\node (z) at (4,4){};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The shapes of some nodes are drawn and the shapes are similar. By default, the shape is a rectangle and with the option `minimum width=1cm` we can get a square.

We want to give the same shape for all nodes also this can be achieved with `every node/.style= minimum width=1cm`. The nodes are placed with 1 cm between the centers

```
\begin{tikzpicture} [every node/.style={minimum size=1cm}] 
\node (e) at (2,0){e}; % {e} label of the node (e) reference or name of the node
\node (t) at (1,1){t};
\node (u) at (0,6){}; % a name but an empty label
% now we draw the shape for the next nodes, we can add an option 
\tikzset{every node/.append style={draw}} 
\node (g) at (4,2){}; 
\node (g) at (5,2){f};   
\node (h) at (6,2){};         
\node (x) at (2,4){x}; 
\node (y) at (3,4){};   
\node (z) at (4,4){};     
\end{tikzpicture}
```

To draw an arrow, you need to give two nodes or two coordinates (start and end): 
For example `\draw[->,>=latex] (y) -- (t);`  draws a line between two nodes. The points at each extremities of the arrow are selected by tikZ. You can give these points

```
 \draw[->,>=latex] (y.center) --(t.north);%
```

The anchors defined by TikZ :

[image]

When you create a node, you define some special points (anchors) around the shape. An option `outer sep`   can be used to modify the positions of anchors around the node. With `outer sep=2pt` , the arrows are placed at 2 pts of the shape. 
 We can change the node style.

`[every node/.style={minimum size=1cm,outer sep=2pt}]` In the next picture you can see the action of `outer sep`. The gray part is added by `outer sep`. You get the same result with other shapes.

[image]

Now to draw a simple arrow like the one between (y)  and (t), we can use :

```
   \draw[->,>=latex] (y.center) to[out=-135,in=90] (t.north);
```

`[->,>=latex]` are options : `->` to get an arrow and `>=latex` for the style of the head.

`[out=-135,in=90]` are options for  the powerful command `to` . The arrow begins with an angle=-135 from the point `(y.center)` and arrives with an angle `90` at `(t.north)`.

The next arrow is more complicated to draw because we need to decompose it in several parts:

```
  \draw[->,>=latex] (h.center) to [out=-90,in=180] +(1,-1) 
                               to [out=0,in=-60] +(+1,+3)
                               to [out=120,in=90] (y.north);
```

start : (h.center) with an angle of -90
  next step : +(1,-1)  these coordinates are relative to last coordinates of (h.center) 
  next step : +(1,+3)
  final : (y.north)

What can we improve?
Like in others answers, we can use  multiple text parts but the principle are the same. There are other possibilities.

Final code :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [every node/.style={minimum size=1cm,outer sep=2pt}] 
\node (e) at (2,0){e}; % {e} label of the node (e) reference or name of the node
\node (t) at (1,1){t};
\node (u) at (0,6){}; 
% we draw the shape for the next nodes we can add an option 
\tikzset{every node/.append style={draw}} 
\node (g) at (4,2){}; 
\node (g) at (5,2){f};   
\node (h) at (6,2){};

\node (x) at (2,4){x}; 
\node (y) at (3,4){};   
\node (z) at (4,4){}; 

\draw[->,>=latex] (u.east) to [out=0,in=120] (y.north);
\draw[->,>=latex] (y.center) to[out=-145,in=90] (t.north); 
\draw[->,>=latex] (h.center) to [out=-90,in=180] +(1,-1) 
                             to [out=0,in=-60] +(+1,+3)
                             to [out=120,in=70] (y.north);

% the arrow is placed at the end of a path. You need to study the concept of path 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I think you can finish the diagram.